# Query Dll layout information

Tags: c++, windows, dll, portable-executable, dllmain

I want to query the following information from a DLL in memory:

- Exact address of entry point (DllMain?!)
- Address and size of the code section of the Dll
- Addresses of entry points of each EXPORTED function

I used `GetModuleInformation()` from the PSAPI functions to query the entry point. But according to MSDN "this is not the address of the `DllMain` function."

Are there any libraries/APIs to query these information?

I need a generic way to query this information which is not dependent on hardcoded strings or something.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: he doesn't know how to get this info, and he asks if one can help

Comment: Not sure what your endgame is here, but be aware that on newer versions of windows, your result may not be the same between runs, even with the same binary. Windows has ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) enabled by default starting with Vista.

Comment: Snooping on DLLs in this way is really not sound engineering practice. It leads to fragile dependencies that break at the slightest provocation. What is the actual problem you're having where you think snooping on DLLs is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint will be returned by `GetModuleInformation()`.

If `DllMain` is exported, use `GetProcAddress()`.

Based on the answers you've refused, I'm more or less at a loss to what you're actually trying to do. If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, you're more likely to get meaningful help.

Comment: Is "DllMain" always the name of the entry function or is it possible to change the name?

Comment: @user2252343 - It is possible to use a different name for the entrypoint. The exact method depends on your linker.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a more generic way which is not linker dependent. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user2252343 - Do you mean in this code or in your DLL? Your question has nothing to do with changing the entrypoint. If you want to know how to change the entrypoint for a DLL, open a new question. If you mean the code, just change the string `"DllMain"` to whichever method you are looking for. Maybe you should actually look up the API documentation for the methods I used.

Comment: I mean your code. I need a way where I dont always need the right name to get it work correctly. I need something which is applicable to every Dll. You are right I didn't mention this is my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user2252343 - What are you trying to accomplish? You already said you know about `GetModuleInformation()`, which returns the entrypoint. I demonstrated `GetProcAddress()`, which will get `DllMain`... so what are you looking for?

Comment: -1. Your code is big mistake, because DLLMain need not be exported.

Comment: Show me DLL which exports DllMain ;)

Comment: I don't agree, now my answer is valid. I showed how to get "Addresses of entry points of each EXPORTET functions" and explained about "Exact address of entry point (DllMain?!)"

Comment: You dont explain HOW TO GET ADDRESS but explain HOW TO NOT GET ADDRESS.